# RETURNING ... INTO: syntax error at or near "INTO"

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

I am trying to return the generated id into a variable so i can use it for inserting referenced values in other tables.

The error does not appear when I delete the 'INTO foo_id_0' part. But this is kind of essential for waht i am trying to do.

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bar(
    foo_id SERIAL UNIQUE,
    one VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    two VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT pk_foo_id PRIMARY KEY (foo_id)
);


INSERT INTO foo(foo_id, one, two) VALUES 
(DEFAULT, 'green' , 'blue' ) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pk_foo_id DO NOTHING RETURNING foo_id INTO foo_id_0;


ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 11: ...ONSTRAINT pk_foo_id DO NOTHING RETURNING foo_id INTO foo_...
                                                            ^
```

Comment: `RETURNING foo_id AS foo_id_0` [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

Comment: what is `foo_id_0` ?

Comment: You can only use variables in PL/pgSQL, not in SQL

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you need to quote the `VARCHAR` column values like

```
INSERT INTO foo(foo_id, one, two) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'green', 'blue')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pk_foo_id DO NOTHING RETURNING foo_id;
```